# how to a create generic retrofit service

Tags: java, android, web-services, retrofit

I create a generic retrofit service like this:

```
public interface GenericService<T>{
    @GET("/repos/{id}")
    //sync
    T all(@Path("id")String id);    

    @GET("/repos/{id}")
    //async
    void all(@path(id) String id, Callback<T> callback);

}
```

---

and have some models:

```
    public class Publication{
          String id;
          User creator;

          //getter & setter 
    }

    public class User{
       String id;
       String nickname;

       //getter & setter

   }
```

---

But found an error like below:

```
11-06 10:14:10.444    3355-3355/com.baoshi.mua E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.baoshi.mua.model.Publication
        at com.baoshi.mua.activities.MainActivity$1.onRequestSuccess(MainActivity.java:96)
        at com.octo.android.robospice.request.notifier.DefaultRequestListenerNotifier$ResultRunnable.run(DefaultRequestListenerNotifier.java:174)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it allowed to create a generic service ?

If allowed, how to fix the error.

Comment: Could you show as an example JSON (if it is JSON you are receiving in your responses)?

Answer (score 0):

This issue rises because of Java runtime erasure, in simple words, Java doesn't know type T at runtime, so Retrofit cannot launch Gson json parser, so you just got the raw JSON string from the service. Additionally, you can relaunch the GSON parser in onSuccess method then your problem will be solved, but this method is not usefull and you simply remove all advantage of Retrofit.